# CCS811 eCO2 readings factors wrong

Tags: esp8266

I have an ESP8266 ([Wemos D1 mini pro v2.0.0](https://wiki.wemos.cc/products:d1:d1_mini_pro)) running [esphome.io](https://esphome.io/) measuring CO<sub>2</sub> with an [Winsen MHZ-19B](https://www.winsen-sensor.com/sensors/co2-sensor/mh-z19b.html) and an [Adafruit AMS CCS811](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3566). I would like to use only the CCS811 to save power and space, however the CCS811 gives weird values

So far, I've tried:

- Burn-in of >168hrs (see below)
- Bought 'original' Adafruit ccs811 as well as no-name ccs811, same issue
- Record baseline value to enable quick power-up
- Correct CCS811 with temperature and RH (from BME280, which' readings are correct)

The best result I’ve had so far is the one below which shows correlation, but not much more. Any ideas?

[image: Adafruit CCS811 eCO2/TVOC readings compared to MH-Z19B CO2]
Adafruit CCS811 eCO2/TVOC readings compared to MH-Z19B CO2

Comment: It is a cheap sensor from which one cannot expect exact values. Even the data sheet does not show any tolerance values!